# How to plot x[t] vs x'[t]?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

Hello please help me to plot my code like the right side plot where I cannot plot the phase plane plot Displacement VS velocity, see plz the attached picture..

Here is my drafted code , Where I got stuck

```
d = 1.18*10^-6; A = 510*100*10^-12; m = 1.784*10^-10;k = 17.96;  \[CurlyEpsilon] = 8.85*10^-12; Subscript[\[Omega],n]^2 = k/m;  Subscript[V, DC] = 1;
x[0] = x'[0] = 0;

MainEquation = {m*x''[t]+(k)*x[t] - (\[CurlyEpsilon]*A* Subscript[V, DC]^2)/(2*(d - x[t])) == 0};  (*x as a function of time*)

sol[t_] = NDSolve[{MainEquation, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}][[1, 1, 2]];

ParametricPlot[{sol[t], sol'[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: you can't write $(\omega_n)^2= \frac{k}{m}$. How did this even work in your mathematica??  what version are you using?

Comment: something wrong with either your ODE's or your numbers. The phase plot I get does not match the plot shown. Need to check carefully what your wrote.

Comment: Are you sure that you gave a right value of k? Your terms are of very different orders of magnitude. Generally, one can select the largest one and throw away all the rest. Then you get `k x[t]==0`. Evidently, it is not expected equation.

Comment: Try `sol = NDSolveValue[..., x,...]`.